# Simplfying Less CSS If "Functions"

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013, less

I am struggling to understand how guarded expressions (from a different topic I am led to believe that these are the LESS equivilant of if functions) can be used to set individual properties. Although the below works it seems a little over the top, however it does allow me to do what I need to do. Is this the best way? If not what would be considered so?

```
.cover() {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.cover(@property, @value) when (@property = "top") {
    position: fixed;
    top: @value;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.cover(@property, @value) when (@property = "bottom") {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: @value;
    left: 0;
}

.cover(@property, @value) when (@property = "left") {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: @value;
}

.cover(@property, @value) when (@property = "right") {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: @value;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

---

This lets my type for example...

```
#cover{
    .cover("left", 55px);
}
```

which renders as

```
#cover{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 55px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use LESS version >= 1.6, you can use dynamic property names, which would reduce your code to this:

```
.cover(@property: left, @value: 0) {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    @{property}: @value;
}
#cover {
    .cover(left, 55px);
}
```

Comment: When I use this inside Visual Studio 2013 with the latest Web Essentials (uses Less compiler 1.6.3) I get the following errors... https://www.dropbox.com/s/kox2yiua5r4342t/Message.png

Comment: Are these errors coming from lessc, or from VS? Do the errors you get prevent actual compilation of the .less file?

Comment: Warnings in Visual Studio, but as soon as I use the .cover(left, 55px) mixin the LESS Files does not compile and I get the following errors. "  SyntaxError: expected ')' got ':'  " interestingly @seven-phases-max solution seems to work, even though it seems very similar.

Comment: For the record, I still get the warnings, but the less file does compile.

Comment: my bad. its because I was calling .cover() empty, earlier in my less file. Remove that it both now compile, I do still get the warnings for both solutions. Most peculiar.

Comment: I have just installed lessc@1.6.3 just to check the error, but it compiles flawlessly (both my and @seven-phases-max's solutions). The errors must be coming from VS - perhaps the built in parser uses an earlier version of LESS? I cannot confirm that as I'm on a Linux box and don't have VS at my disposal :(.

Comment: On the basis the code does exactly what I want I am happy to mark as answer. I'd like to say the Warning are only warnings and I'll ignore them, but I suspect i'll try to fix them in the future because they will annoy me :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the @mingos answer, an optimized impl. (i.e. with no redudant properties in output) could look like:

```
.cover(@property: top, @value: 0) {
    position: fixed;
    top:    @t;
    right:  @r;
    bottom: @b;
    left:   @l;

    .-(@property);
    .-(...)    {@t: 0; @r: 0; @b: 0; @l: 0}
    .-(top)    {@t: @value}
    .-(right)  {@r: @value}
    .-(bottom) {@b: @value}
    .-(left)   {@l: @value}
}

// usage:
.a {.cover(left,  55px)}
.b {.cover(right, 33px)}
```

Comment: works like a charm. Had to add default property values to ensure that I could call it empty, but other than that (and the silly visual studio warnings) perfect :)

Comment: I used "" for the @property, so that I could call .cover() and it would cover the entire area, but yeah thats the trick :)